# I can't see where cause the error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: arrays, parsing, for-loop, nested, integer

I have a method showing error but I don't know where is the problem.

```
row = 1700

public void setCodeName(){
    this.code = new Integer[this.row];

    f or(int i=0; i<this.row; i++){
        for(int y=0; y<2; i++){
            if(y==0){
                this.code[i]=Integer.parseInt(this.sn[i][0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the console gives me

> Exception in thread "main"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:1700
>   at Stockname.setCodeName(Stockname.java:40)

thanks for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner 'for' loop for y is incrementing 'i' (resulting in an infinite loop until i gets too large), so it should be :

```
for(int y=0; y<2; y++){
```